# How to make a wall post using windows phone 7 native app

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7.1

I have created a native app on Windows Phone 7.

The user of the app will provide his login credentials to us when he registers as a new user. What i want to do is to give a handle of share on facebook in my app.

On clicking on the handle the selected image should be posted on to the user's wall and just display a message to the user that the image is posted successfully  or not.

The problem is that facebook has not provided with a developent environment for Windows Phone 7 native apps.

I want some alternate solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the link. I had already visited the link earlier. I have implemented facebook integration in wp7. Its working properly and i am able to make wall posts.

Here's my code,

//Users clicks on Share on facebook button

private void btnFacebookPost_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

```
       //Check if access tokens are already set.
        if (App.accessTokens == null)
        {
            GetAccessTokens();
        }
        else
        {
            //Use the access tokens to post on facebook
        }

    }
```

private void GetAccessTokens()
        {

```
       // Navigate user to facebooks login page
       // if user has already authenticated your app you'll receive the access tokens directly


        webBrowser.Source = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='your app id'&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&scope='whatever extended permissions you require'");

    }
```

//On The Navigated event of web browser check for access tokens
//Use the facebook c# sdk to get the access tokens from the url

void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

```
        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();

            FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
            if (fbClient.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out oauthResult))
            {
                // The url is the result of OAuth 2.0 authentication
                if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
                {

                    App.accessTokens = oauthResult.AccessToken;

                }
                else
                {

                    var errorDescription = oauthResult.ErrorDescription;
                    var errorReason = oauthResult.ErrorReason;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The url is NOT the result of OAuth 2.0 authentication.
            }

      }
```

Now use the access tokens with the facebook sdk for C#.net to make the wall posts or any other transactions as required.

The problem with this method is that the application user and the facebook's logged in user may be different thus making a transaction to different account.
Since the SSO for WP7 is not available this method should do the trick.